# как продолжить нумерацию строк матрицы pandas при их добавлении после удаления начала матрицы?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, матрицы, индексы

У меня создаётся матрица в pandas, объем которой очень большой. csv файл с матрицей 28Гб. Для дальнейшей работы с матрицей не хватает оперативной памяти.

1. Часть информации проанализирована, и хочется её удалить, это к сожалению вызывает некоторые проблемы с дальнейшей правильной генерацией матрицы, если есть предложения, напишите, пожалуйста.
2. Из того что придумал, это удалить всё ниже определённой строки и начать добавлять новые строки. К сожалению нумерация новых строк не продолжается. Как посоветуете добавлять строки в матрицу после удаления через ".drop" строк условно с 0 по 300000 строку. Добавление строк условно с 400000 строки (400001 ...) через ".loc".
3. Создание новой матрицы, как продолжение старой, строки условно с 300000 по 400000 копируются и снова вопрос о продолжении нумерации. Принципиальной разницы с п.2 вроде нет, кроме сохранения данных и работе с новым файлом.

Comment: А в матрице то что находится? Вообще слова `матрица` и `Pandas` не шибко сочетаются. Хотите работать с матрицами - используйте `numpy`, `scipy`. Если матрица *разреженная*, то, возможно, вы можете и ничего не удалять, и у вас останется полно свободного места в памяти, если будете использовать правильный тип данных https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html
А `Pandas` - он для `таблиц`.

Comment: Спасибо! Да, можно рассматривать как таблицу состоящую из 0 и 1. И да в ней много "0". и её можно считать разреженной матрицей. Матрица (таблица) расширяется в право и в низ в соответствии с производимыми расчетами. Расчеты простые. Я самоучка в программировании, мне казалось что pandas таблицы состоят из np.array. Я правильно понимаю, что вы советуете в scipy.sparse выполнить формирование исходных данных, и 0 ничего не будут весить?

Comment: Именно так. Да, в `Pandas` хранятся `numpy.array`, но хранятся очень неэффективно. Если у вас однотипные данные, а не разнотипные столбцы, то `Pandas` вам не нужен, он только память и вычислительные ресурсы у вас отнимет. Судя по всему у вас идеальный случай для того, чтобы оставаться в пространстве разреженных матриц. Но нужно понимать, что вы делаете, чтобы не выйти в любой момент в "плотные матрицы" и не потерять внезапно на этом всё ОЗУ )

Comment: Плохо только, что матрица расширяется в двух измерениях сразу. Там разные типы оптимальны для построчного хранения разреженных матриц и для хранения столбцами. С этим может быть всё не так просто. Но в целом если вам удастся остаться в пространстве разреженных матриц, то экономия памяти будет реально очень большая. Что-то типа того, что там хранятся только координаты единиц в матрице, поэтому чем больше отношение количества нулей к количеству единиц, тем больше экономия памяти. При этом там есть методы для эффективной работы с такими матрицами типа их умножения и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!
Рост происходит поочередно по направлениям. А значит может быть разделён.
Буду разбираться со scipy.sparse
Огромный плюс вам в карму!
Я лишь буду надеяться что и все мои старания не напрасны и получится что-то стоящее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задачка не до конца понятна - нет примера данных и нет ожидаемого результата.
Попробуйте использовать чтение `.csv` частями с последующим их объединением.

1. Нумерация сквозная - индекс формируется автоматически
2. Каждая часть пересекается с предыдущей (новая часть является продолжением старой) - см. индексы 0-5, 3-8 и т.д.

```
import pandas as pd

def process(x, part_num):
    # как-то обрабатываем
    print(f'Часть {part_num}', x, sep='\n')

# на основе https://stackoverflow.com/a/47661438/15035314
cnt, pred_chunk = 0, None
for chunk in pd.read_csv(r'c:\test\sample.csv', chunksize=3, sep=';'):
    if pred_chunk is not None:
        cnt += 1
        process(pd.concat([pred_chunk, chunk]), cnt) # объединяем предыдущую и текущую части
    pred_chunk = chunk
```

Исходный .csv:

```
Id;Number
id3429;4300805
id7888;4361596
id4590;5191255
id1742;9785553
id2273;9304280
id2404;2398939
id9030;7501318
id1233;6004036
id4664;8726154
id1891;7248669
id5406;7538215
id4529;6783776
id5567;1724566
id6008;9824435
id4266;2872342
id9933;4004131
id5088;8458978
id1017;6279474
id7245;8393577
id1535;7047548
id6765;7572237
id8556;2842737
...
```

Вывод:

```
Часть 1
       Id   Number
0  id3429  4300805
1  id7888  4361596
2  id4590  5191255
3  id1742  9785553
4  id2273  9304280
5  id2404  2398939
Часть 2
       Id   Number
3  id1742  9785553
4  id2273  9304280
5  id2404  2398939
6  id9030  7501318
7  id1233  6004036
8  id4664  8726154
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я правильно понимаю, что часть 1 и часть 2, это выгрузки из исходного .csv?
У меня проблема в том, что исходный csv обработан и мне надо строить его (csv) дальше как продолжение предыдущего. А в расчетах важна строка. И я думаю, что можно перенести номер строки в 1 столбец и формировать его отдельной функцией. Всё равно прирост данных сейчас такой большой, что выгрузить целиков это сразу забить всю  память и не полуить файл.

Comment: Без понимания способа обработки данных, образца данных и ожидаемого результата, которые не раскрыты, сложно предложить конкретное решение. Поэтому решение я предложил исходя из той информации, которая есть в пп.1-3. В нем номер строки - в данном случае индекс - формируется автоматически, отдельный столбец не требуется.